# PHP three dimensional array, reset key if second element different

Tags: php, arrays

Let say i have this `print_r` output, this is dynamic and not same each condition

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 23,25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [3] => 27
            [4] => 27,26
            [5] => 28,27,26
        )

)
```

As you can see, array element `[3]` starts from `[3][4][5]`, how do it make it start from `[1][2]...[n]` if the 2nd element is not same.

Ideally what i am looking for is something like

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 23,25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 27
            [2] => 27,26
            [3] => 28,27,26
        )

)
```

How do i achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Not only that, but what's your code?

Comment: @Truth, i am using jQuery to pass the product ID and product location, the 2nd element is product ID and third element is their position in tree, `parseInt($(this).closest('.plist').prevAll().length)-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) returns the values of an array with new numeric indices:

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
  $a[$k] = array_values($v);
}
```

Add conditions if you only want to re-index some of your sub-arrays.

---

Functional approach:

```
$a = array_map(function($v) {
  return array_values($v);
}, $a);
```

Comment: hmm, when i use this method, the 3rd array become wrong if new values added to same array

Comment: @cicakman: third array? I see only two arrays in your question

Comment: yea, sorry looked wrong, i meant was, second array values get added up more when new values added into second array